# Apply a search and replace regexp to all the file in a folder in java

Tags: java, regex, file

I searched on the net and I found only examples that open each file and apply the regexp to the content.
Is there a way to apply the regexp to all the files in a folder?
the same I would do with "grep" on linux but I need to write a portable code.

Comment: Break this task into its constituent components.  Do you know how to get all the files in a directory?  Check.  Do you know how to search within one file using a regex pattern?  Check.  Put it all together...

Comment: I'm sure someone would've come up with a library to do that. Don't try to write one yourself unless you're learning.

Comment: right that's what I guessed. There should be something already done...

Comment: @adarshr, that "wisdom" can be taken too far.  It's not like this involves more than a few lines of code.

Comment: Do you really need to code it in java?  'grep', 'sed', 'awk', and 'find' are pretty much available anywhere.  I would classify that as portable... granted you need something like cygwin on Windows.

Comment: right and I would like to avoid having to install cygwin

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
for(File file : directory.listFiles())
{
    if(file.isFile())
    {
        String name = file.getName();
        String newName = name.replaceAll("foo","bar");
        file.renameTo(newName);
    }
}
```

Comment: no it was about applying a regexp to the content of the files like grep